# I need to know how to loop through an array in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, foreach

I want to make a method with vuejs that loop through an array of object and give me all the names in that array, but i dont know how

the method will be something like this:

```
fruits =[
  {name: "apple", calories: "50"},
  {name: "apple", calories: "100"},
];
methode(){
  var names = ''
  foreach(fruit in this.fruits){
     names = names+friut.name
  }
  return names
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: no it's not the same case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
fruits =[
  {name: "apple", calories: "50"},
  {name: "apple", calories: "100"},
];

getNameList(){
  return this.fruits.map(fruit => fruit.name)
}
```

Comment: it works but it gives me result like this **[ "apple", "tag apple" ]** but i want it like this: **apple,apple** not in a array

Comment: Just add a `.toString()` in the end. `getNameList(){
  return this.fruits.map(fruit => fruit.name).toString()
}`

Comment: it works just fine but in the console it gives me this error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"**

Comment: The error message says everything, you are sending an undefined object to this function. Double check your array.